# woocommerce - insert video into product gallery slider

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to insert an embed video(youtube) into the product galley slider that appears on product page.

So far i'm working with

```
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html','my function');
```

to add the video thumb but i don't know what are the filters to add the new content in woocommerce-product-gallery div (where the larger images are) or in the light box .

Also the 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html' hook runs after each thumb so it will be nice if i would use a filter that runs before/after the thumbs are displayed. I've try to use

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'my_function', 20 );
```

but it does not work.

So the question is : what are the hooks i need to use to add new thumbs and new slides in the woocommerce product slider.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: no, i ended up putting the video after the slider